# ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for DishService

Tags: angular

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';

@Injectable()
export class DishService {

  getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes');
  }

  getDish(id: string): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + id);
  }

  getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true').pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]));
  }

  getDishIds(): Observable<number[] | any> {
    return this.getDishes().pipe(map(dishes => dishes.map(dish => dish.id)));
  }
    constructor(private dishService: DishService,private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL: any) {}
  
}
```

**I cannot load my code on my localhost**
I cannot load my code on my localhost
I'm learning angular with Coursera. This code is an exercise on my course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `private dishService: DishService` from the `constructor`. As it depends on itself which cause the infinite loop.

```js
@Injectable()
export class DishService {

  ...

 constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL: any) {}
  
}
```

---

### References

[NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected while instantiating a provider - Debugging the error](https://angular.io/errors/NG0200)

Comment: Thank you so much, I fixed it for the past 2 weeks but it still doesn't work, thanks to you I fixed it